# me sale este error:Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\maestro\modificar.php on line 4

Tags: php

Estoy programando una base de datos para hacer unas encuestas y me sale este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\maestro\modificar.php
>   on line 4

He aquí el código hoja modificar

```
<?php
    require 'conexion.php';

    $id = $_GET['id'];                                                                                                                                                  

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = '$id'";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>
<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3 style="text-align:center">MODIFICAR REGISTRO</h3>
            </div>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="update.php" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Identificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Identificacion</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Identificacion" name="Identificacion" placeholder="Identificacion" value="<?php echo $row['Identificacion']; ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Nombre y Apellido" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre Funcionario</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="Nombre y Apellido" class="form-control" id="NomApeFuncionario" name="NomApeFuncionario" placeholder="NomApeFuncionario" value="<?php echo $row['NomApeFuncionario']; ?>"  required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Entidad" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Entidad</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="Entidad" class="form-control" id="Entidad" name="Entidad" placeholder="Entidad" value="<?php echo $row['Entidad']; ?>" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probablemente no tienes $_GET['id'], de dónde lo traes?

Comment: Si estás enviando un formulario al servidor, ten en cuenta que en el mismo debe haber un elemento cuya `name="id"`, de lo contrario, tendrás un Undefined index aquí: `$id = $_GET['id'];`. Si quieres ver lo que hay en todo el `GET` puedes hacer esto: `print_r($_GET);` como `$_GET` es un array, te mostrará las claves/valores que fueron pasadas al servidor. En cualquier caso, deberías usar `isset` o `empty` para obtener tu valor, una vez corregido lo de la etiqueta  `name` antes mencionado.

Comment: $_GET['id'];  no existe por eso el error

Answer (score 7):

La variable `$_GET` simplemente está intentando leer una variable en la URL, algo como `modificar.php?id=xx`. El php debe tener activado el nivel más alto de error (`display_error=ALL` en php.ini), y por eso está desplegando este aviso.

De todas formas viendo tu consulta, este id es obligatorio, así que deberías comprobar primero que el id se está pasando por URL, o de lo contrario mostrar un mensaje diciendo que es necesario o algo parecido. Sería algo como:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

if (empty($_GET['id'])) {
   echo "ID es requerido.";
} else {
   $id = $_GET['id'];                                                                                                                                                  

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = '$id'";
   $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
   $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

Posiblemente reenviar a otra pantalla o mostrar un error o algo así. Depende de la lógica que estés implementando.

Answer (score 7):

Hay principalmente  dos motivos por los que un envío del tipo `GET` puede dar un *`Undefine index`*:

1. Cuando el formulario es enviado, los elementos del mismo son serializados como un array donde la clave equivaldrá a lo que haya escrito en la etiqueta `name` de los elementos  y el valor equivaldrá al dato que haya en el elemento. Los elementos que no tienen etiqueta `name` por tanto no son serializados ni enviados al servidor.

   Si tenemos por ejemplo este formulario:

   ```
   <form action="modificar.php" method="get">
           <label for="name">Nombre:</label> <br />
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/> <br />
           <label for="lastname">Apellido:</label> <br />
           <input type="text" id="lastname" /> <br />
           <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
           <input type="email" id="mail" name="email"/> <br />
           <label for="msg">Message:</label>
           <textarea id="msg" name="msg"></textarea>        
   </form>
   ```

   Cuando se envíe **el apellido no será serializado ni enviado**, porque no tiene etiqueta `name`. `$_GET` en el caso de este formulario será un array así cuando el mismo sea enviado:

   ```
   $_GET = array 
           (
               "name"=>"Lo escrito en name",
               "mail"=>"Lo escrito en mail",
               "msg"=>"Lo escrito en msg"
           )
   ```

   Es por eso que podemos acceder a los valores de `$_GET` como se hace con cualquier array, mediante la notación: `$_GET["clave"]`.  Si en este caso se intenta algo como `$_GET["lastname"]` tendremos una noticia de *`Undefined index*`.
2. Otro motivo por el que se puede tener *`Undefined index`* es por algo muy simple: el nombre de archivo que hay en el atributo `action` del formulario. Si el formulario se está enviando al archivo llamado `modificar.php`, pero por error te confundes y crees que el archivo es `update.php`, podrías estar buscando los datos en el sitio equivocado. Es como equivocarse de oficina de correos: la carta no fue mandada a la oficina `update.php` sino a la oficina `modificar.php`. Eso puede ocurrir incluso si el archivo se llama igual, pero está en otra carpeta. En el `action` hay que poner el archivo y la ruta (absoluta o relativa) específica.

   Es cierto que es un error poco probable, pero puede ocurrir. De hecho, tu mensaje de error me hace dudar al respecto, porque habla de un archivo `modificar.php` y en el `action` del formulario que presentas está indicado un archivo `update.php`. Quizá presentas otro formulario, quizá sea el mismo.

Si es el mismo formulario estarías entonces incurriendo en este caso de error al postear los datos hacia una oficina de correos e irlos a buscar luego a otra oficina.

Si es otro formulario sugeriría que empieces a aplicar una política de nombrado coherente. Es confuso tener por un lado un archivo `modificar.php` y por otro lado un archivo `update.php` (parecería que son dos archivos distintos destinados a lo mismo, a actualizar datos). Por coherencia se entiende también que si vas a optar por una convención de nombres en inglés (lo cual no está mal, yo particularmente la prefiero), pongas en inglés todo (archivos, variables, clases, etc).

Recomiendo también coherencia en los métodos. Si en el formulario pones el método `POST`, recoge los datos con `POST`, si pones `GET`, recoge los datos con `GET`. A veces funciona intercambiar, pero no es coherente.

> Cabe decir que todo lo dicho hasta ahora también para `$_POST` o para `$_REQUEST`

---

#### Algunos aspectos del código PHP

En cuanto al código PHP, recomendaría que apliques buenas prácticas. El código no debería recoger sin más los datos que son pasados por `$_GET`, **ni mucho menos pasarlos a ejecución concatenados en una consulta SQL**. A través del dato que recoges con GET un usuario mal intencionado podría preparar todo un ataque a tu sistema que puede ser cualquier cosa, desde borrar, modificar, obtener datos sensibles de la base de datos, hasta introducirse en el sistema de archivos, etc. (aquí ya hay varias preguntas que tratan a fondo el serio problema de la *Inyección SQL*).

Para prevenir esto es bueno evaluar el estado del GET y usar consultas preparadas. Si por ejemplo la consulta no debe ser lanzada sin ese dato, no la lanzas al comprobar que el dato está vacío.

Escribiría el PHP así para corregir lo dicho:

```
<?php 

    $id = (!empty ($_GET['id']) ) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;                 #1                                                                                                                                                
    if ( $id ) {                                                        #2
        require 'conexion.php';                                         #3
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = ?";    #4
        $stmt= $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);                                     #5
        $stmt->execute();                                               #6
        $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();                                    #7
    } else {
        echo "No se posteó valor para el ID, revise el formulario";
    }
?>
```

Aquí yo recojo el `id` según un ternario (`#1`). Luego pregunto si realmente tiene datos (`#2`). Observa que sólo entonces se incluye la conexión (`#3`), es un principio a tener en cuenta: no traigas nada hasta que no estés seguro de que lo vas a usar.

Luego se escribe una consulta preparada con un marcador `?` en lugar del dato real que antes pasabas directamente y que alguien podría amañar para hacer estragos en tu sistema (`#4`). El dato en sí es pasado mediante el método `bind_param` que detectará si hay algún intento de trampa. La `i` indica que es un dato del tipo `i`nteger (entero). Si es una cadena la cambias por una `s` (`#5`). Luego se ejecuta la consulta (`#6`).

Finalmente, usamos el método específico para arrays asociativos que es `fetch_assoc` (`#7`), es lo mismo que `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`, pero yo opté por una forma más directa y más elegante si se quiere. Conviene siempre para cada cosa usar el método más específico.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 6):

Como el mensaje lo indica `id` no esta definido, únicamente comprueba que lo que viene por la url este definido con `isset()`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $id = $_GET['id'];                                                                                                                                                  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

noté que muestras el archivo que *'recibe'* el (id), pero no muestras qué archivo o la forma que envías ese (id). El ejemplo que comparto, es un formulario 'previo', que envía el (id) mediante un **input-type 'hidden'**, por otro lado, **debes cambiar el 'POST' por 'GET' en la propiedad 'method'**, ya con eso creo que te serviría.

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];                                                                                                                                                  

$sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = '$id'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="GET" action="modificar.php" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Identificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Identificacion</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Identificacion" name="Identificacion" placeholder="Identificacion" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="241">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar a modificar.php</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre que uses el **NULL COALECSE OPERATOR** presente en PHP 7 para controlar el flujo de tu código del modo siguiente

```
 $id = $_GET['id'] ?? 0;                                                                                                                                                  

if($id > 0){
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM encuestador WHERE id_encuestador = '$id'";
      $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
      $row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}else{
     echo "El id".$id." no es un valor válido para realizar la consulta";
}
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Verificamos si la variable `$id` tiene un valor asociado y en caso contrario le asignamos el valor 0
- Con un condicional verificamos, si el `$id` esta mayor a 0 entonces se pasó un valor válido como id para hacer la consulta y la procesamos
- En caso contrario que el id sea contrario a la primer condición dada retornamos un mensaje indicando que no se pudo llevar a cabo

Answer (score 1):

Esta muy facil, los metodos $_GET son variables que se obtienen de la url en este caso index.php?id=21 y al paracer no lo esta recibiendo, lo que puedes hacer primero es verificar que el valor si exista, tambien puedes verificar que no este vacío.

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) AND !empty($_GET['id'])) {
     $id = $_GET['id'];                                                                                                                                                  

     $sql = "codigo sql";
     $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
     $row = $resultado->fetch_array(tipo);
} else {
     echo 'El valor no existe o esta vacío';
}
```

Tambien el problema puede estar ocurriendo por que estas enviando los datos en $_POST

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="update.php" autocomplete="off">
```

Cambia ese method="POST" por method="GET"

Y por ultimo, deberia leer toda la documentación de bootstrap, estas usando style en HTML innecesario como por ejemplo

```
<h3 style="text-align:center">MODIFICAR REGISTRO</h3>
```

Para eso tiene la clase text-center y asi un sin fin de clases para ese tipo de cosas